# flipping between 3 view controllers on iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, view, controllers

I have 3 view controllers. Main view (controller1's view) is displayed first. Based on button selection the 2nd view (controller2's view) is displayed. There are several buttons and a home button on this view. Selecting those will display 3rd view (controller3's view) with animation.Selecting home button will display the main view(controller1' view). The issue I have is when I press buttons on controller2's view to display controller3's view, during animation I see the controller1's view in the background. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: How do you display your view controllers? Do you use UINavigationController or smth else?

Comment: No I dont use UINavigationController

In application's delegate I add [window addSubview: viewController1.view]

Then within each controller's implementation file I instantiate the next view controller from NIB and add it as subview.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want to use `presentModalViewController`. That probably wont fix your other problem with view1 being visible during the animation. I'd try and set the `hidden` property to use for view1.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove controller1's view from the superview before the animation sequence.  You should be doing this as part of the transition from controller1 to controller2.

```
[controller1.view removeFromSuperView];
```

Of course, you will need to add it back in at some point.

Comment: I have to have this line of code in the 2nd controller's file. How do I remember the 1st controller? Should I pass it as argument? I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Are you using a UIView animation block?  If so, it should be part of that block.  Which means in would be in the first controller, or the action method for the button push.